# What is the difference between a method and a function?

Tags: python, oop

What's the difference between a method and a function  in oop ?

Comment: A method is a function that is part of a class.  It gets called through an object, as in `obj.method()`, as opposed to a non-method function, which is called `func(a,b,c)`.

Answer (score 0):

A method is a function of a class.